# Angular SSR (Universal) Website not working with keycloak-js adapter and keycloak-angular plugin

Tags: angular, keycloak, angular-universal, keycloak-angular, keycloak-js

I am strugling to translate my website to Angular SSR for better SEO ranking.

I manage to handle window, document, localStorgae calls in website.

But when I check whole site with Keycloak integration it fails due to window issue again.

I follow this post: [Keycloak SSO with Angular Universal SSR](https://keycloak.discourse.group/t/keycloak-sso-with-angular-universal-ssr/2735), but no luck, it has typo error in the last step. It might be the reason.

Can anyone point me to the right direction.

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: hi. i have a same issue. Any progress?

Answer (score 1):

Facing the same problem and solved for me as follow :

I'm using a Keycloak Server (self-hosting) v21.1.1, Angular app v16.0.5. and keycloak-angular package V14.0.0

First, I've followed keycloak-angular setup : https://www.npmjs.com/package/keycloak-angular#setup and modified `initializeKeycloak` function like this :

```
declare var require: any;
const Keycloak = typeof window !== 'undefined' ? require('keycloak-js') : null;

export function initializeKeycloak(
  keycloak: KeycloakService
  ) {
    if(Keycloak!==null){
      return () =>
            keycloak.init({
              config: {
                //my config
              },
              initOptions:{
                // my options
              }
            });
    }else{
      return ()=>{
        return new Promise<Boolean>((resolve,reject)=>{
          resolve(true);
        });
      }
    }
}
```

Some comments :

First two lines will be used to know if 'window' exists or not (i.e. if code run in server or browser side).
(found here : [code for SSR but using keycloak-js](https://github.com/ozanturhan/angular-ssr-keycloak-integration-tutorial/blob/master/src/app/keycloak.service.ts))

Then, simply make an if statement on `Keycloak` variable (null or not) and return expected format `()=>Promise<Boolean>` in both cases.

Comment: I have an issue with this method. Need to call  keycloakService.getToken() in server side which doesn't work.